# How to count unique values that are present in 2 different sheets only if they exist in both sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**[Goal]**

I want to be able to count unique values that are present in 2 different sheets only if they exist in both sheets.

**[Details]**

First, there are 2 sample data sheets ([Data A](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G_7mDgBb1P_v2_mgJYnBBxfYgl6LCs4Lmj7bLlvkonU/edit#gid=0), [Data B](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G_7mDgBb1P_v2_mgJYnBBxfYgl6LCs4Lmj7bLlvkonU/edit#gid=860121148)) within the same Spreadsheet and it also has a sample dashboard to do the calculations. One thing to note about the data sheets is that **they have different ranges**, so they have different number of columns and rows. However, a couple things they have in common are the Month and ID columns.

Next, in the [Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G_7mDgBb1P_v2_mgJYnBBxfYgl6LCs4Lmj7bLlvkonU/edit#gid=1769958565) sheet, there are 3 cells where B3 is the Month selector, C3 is to count the number of unique IDs that are included in both sheets (Data A & Data B) based on the month. With D3, I would like to count the number of unique IDs that are included in both sheets (Data A & Data B) where the the Month are the same AND Data B sheet's Cumulative column is 1.

**[What I tried so far]**

I tried using the [COUNTUNIQUEIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9584429?hl=en) function and had the range as an array (by using the curly bracket) in the below way, however, it didn't work.

`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS('Data A'!$B:$B,'Data A'!$A:$A,B3,'Data B'!$A:$A,B3)`

I also tried without making the range argument an array.

`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS('Data A'!$B:$B,'Data B'!$A:$A,B3)`

Both attempts results in 1 for February 2023 when it should return 2. The weird thing is that January 2023 should return 3 and it correctly returns 3.

Hope someone can help me out with this. If there's a more elegant solution to achieve this by using Google Apps Scripts, I'd like to see hear about that as well.

Comment: About `Both attempts results in 1 for February 2023 when it should return 2.`, When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand the logic that the rows of `2023-02,789,Email,1,Missed Target` and `2023-02,5678,No,1,Met Target` in "Data B" sheet are not included in your expected result. When these are included, I thought that the count might be 4 instead of 2. How about this? Can I ask you about the detail of the logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: @tanaike Thank you for looking into my question! I decided to remove the Channel and Target columns as they're not necessary. So all we need is: Data A's Month & ID; Data B's Month, ID & Cumulative columns. I also noticed that you'd get an #VALUE! error (Array arguments to COUNTUNIQUEIFS are of different size.) if the column or row sizes between Data A & B sheets are different. The real data sheets I use on a daily basis have different column and row sizes because I copy data from different sources every week, so if there's a way to circumvent them, that'd be really nice.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the logic for achieving 2 from your sample 2 sheets. I apologize for this.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try filtering both ranges for month, and the FILTER again by comparing them with MATCH and counting the remaining results:

```
=LAMBDA(ar,br,COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(ar,NOT(ISERROR (MATCH(ar,br,0))))))
(FILTER('Data A'!B:B,'Data )A'!A:A=B3),FILTER('Data B'!B:B,'Data B'!A:A=B3))
```

And just add an additional filter for the next column and the cumulative =1 `'Data B'!C:C=1`

`=LAMBDA(ar,br,COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(ar,NOT(ISERROR (MATCH(ar,br,0)))))) (FILTER('Data A'!B:B,'Data )A'!A:A=B3),FILTER('Data B'!B:B,'Data B'!A:A=B3,'Data B'!C:C=1))`

[image]